# Setup default CSS class for Rails' form builder helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, formbuilder

I'm looking for a generic way to apply some external CSS frameworks in a Rails application. These frameworks typically define a set of class names which should be used for certain HTML elements.

Consider jQuery UI. To achive a consistent form style, you would to something like this:

```rb
# in a view
<% form_for @foo do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.text_field :bar, :class => ['ui-widget', 'ui-widget-content', 'ui-widget-container', 'ui-corner-all'] %>
  or
  <%= f.text_field :bar, :class => 'ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-widget-container ui-corner-all' %>
<% end %>
```

Doing this for each input field is not DRY at all.

Even a helper method like

```rb
# in application_helper.rb
def jquery_ui_classes
  'ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-widget-container ui-corner-all'
end

# in a view
<%= f.text_field :bar, :class => jquery_ui_classes %>
```

or

```rb
# in application_helper.rb
def jquery_text_field(form_builder, method, opts = {})
  ui = ['ui-widget', 'ui-widget-content', 'ui-widget-container', 'ui-corner-all']
  klass = [opts.delete(:class), ui].flatten.compact
  form_builder.text_field method opts.merge(:class => klass)
end

# in a view
<%= jquery_text_field f, :bar %>
```

does not look right (or more DRY), since you still would have to touch the generated form view...

Alternative ways might now be monkey-patching the `InstanceTag` class or hacking into the `form_for` helper.

Has anyone done this before?

By the way: I would avoid using jQuery (or Javascript in general) to apply the class attributes, since JS might be disabled or blocked or even delivered with delay and cause a flickering...

Cheers,
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/phallstrom/form_helper_css

You can't specify the classes you want, but it will add reasonable class names to all inputs to allow you to easily target them (in all browsers).

Comment: At least, that's a great point to start to build a more general way of adding framework-specific classes. Thank you!